# Oxidation of 2-Methyl, 2-Phenyl Propane

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

Considering oxidation mechanism of side-chains in arenes, it is known that side-chains get oxidized to carboxylic group ($-COOH$).

Below is a picture of 2-Methyl, 2-Phenyl Propane. When it gets refluxed with acidified $KMnO_4$ or acidified $K_2Cr_2O_7$, it should be oxidized to give benzoic acid.

But according to the provided source, it seems 2-Methyl, 2-Phenyl Propane doesn't react with the above oxidizing agents.

My question is,

**Why does this compound disobey the general oxidation of benzyl derivatives?**

Note, the source has a OH on position 4 of the ring, that makes it difficult for me to name it.

*Source:* https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Chemistry%20(9701)/9701_s13_qp_41.pdf
**Qno:5 c) i)**

Or is the OH that makes the difference in this question?

**2-Methyl,2-Phenyl Propane:**

[image]

Comment: For oxidation of aromatic side chains, you must have at least one Benzylic hydrogen. tert-butyl Benzene (which is actually 2-methyl,2-phenyl propane) doesn't have any benzylic hydrogen..

Comment: @SoumikDas Oh, hadn't considered that? Should I remove this thread?

Comment: @Amar30657 No. I rather suggest either comment or answer your own question to let others with the doubt have it answered on ChemSE; you may close the question later on. (The question has been answered by Soumik, tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For oxidation of aromatic side chains, you must have at least one Benzylic hydrogen. tert-butyl Benzene (which is actually 2-methyl,2-phenyl propane) doesn't have any benzylic hydrogen.

**-By @Soumik Das**